# Angular 5 HTTP Get request Parameters - Send multiple objects

Tags: angular, angular5, angular-http

I am trying to make an HTTP get request with an object as param. It's this possible?
I already tried it multiple ways but without success. It works if I send only strings, not the entire class

```
export class City {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}

  const params = new HttpParams().set('city', city)
  return this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/api/place/', {params})
```

Comment: No. Parameters are part of the URL. They are strings. Why would the backend need to receive the name of the city if it already receives its ID? The ID uniquely identifies the city, right? So, if it receives the ID, it can find the name (if even needed) in its database of cities.

Comment: @JBNizet that's just an example. I don't want to get city details but I get your idea. I should do a post instead.

Comment: A post is for creating a resource. If you want to get a resource, you should use GET. But without a concrete explanation of what you want to do, it's hard to advise.

Comment: @JBNizet I want to make a GET request but I need parameters from two different classes and I thought that i would be allowed to send the entire object to parameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a little helper function that JSON-encodes any Object-like properties in an object, leaves primitives as string. Obviously you need to decode the query in the backend. Change _.isObjectLike to some other way of checking the type if you don't want lodash.

```
require * as '_' from 'lodash';
private objectToHttpParams(obj: any) {
    return Object.entries(obj || {})
      .reduce((params, [key, value]) => {
        return params.set(key, _.isObjectLike(value) ? JSON.stringify(value) : String(value));
      }, new HttpParams());
  }

// use:
const params = this.objectToHttpParams({city});
```